# command line autocomplete does not work in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: awk, 19.10

when trying to access the autocompletion in ubuntu 19.10 it always throw an error:

```
awk: line 18: function gensub never defined
```

I think there are some system libs have wrong version or linked to wrong version of dependencies.

Any idea how to fix this or work around it?

Comment: @starkus please provide that as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: naughty ubuntu, it seems the main awk got switch to mawk and gawk is not in the dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read here: 
[bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/1845529](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/1845529)

`sudo apt install gawk` can avoid this problem

In the last answer of this report a guy pointed out to the debian bug, also already reported: [bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=933934](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=933934)